# Why realloc of char** gives Address is 0 bytes after alloc'd

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc, dynamic-allocation

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char* filename = "file_prefix.txt";
  FILE* file_prefix = fopen(filename, "r");

  char buff[1024];
  int i = 0;
  char** prefix = NULL;

  char c = fscanf(file_prefix, "%s", buff);
  while ( EOF != c )
  {
    printf("%d : %s\n", i, buff);
    char** temp  = realloc(prefix, sizeof(char*) * (i+1));
    temp[i] = malloc( (sizeof(char) * strlen(buff)) + 1);
    strcpy(temp[i], buff );
    prefix = temp;
    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
    c = fscanf(file_prefix, "%s", buff);
    ++i;
  } 

  int x = 0;
  for (;x < i; ++x) {
    printf("%s\n", prefix[i]);
  }
  free(prefix);

  fclose(file_prefix);
  return 0;
}
```

Assuming `file_prefix.txt` exists I get the following with valgrind:

```
==7322== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7322== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7322== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7322== Command: ./main
==7322== 
0 : pdf
1 : txt
==7322== Invalid read of size 8
==7322==    at 0x400A6D: main (main.c:29)
==7322==  Address 0x51fc370 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==7322==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7322==    by 0x400976: main (main.c:18)
==7322== 
==7322== Invalid read of size 1
==7322==    at 0x4C2E0E2: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7322==    by 0x4EA6E3B: puts (ioputs.c:36)
==7322==    by 0x400A77: main (main.c:29)
==7322==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7322== 
==7322== 
==7322== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7322==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==7322==    at 0x4C2E0E2: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7322==    by 0x4EA6E3B: puts (ioputs.c:36)
==7322==    by 0x400A77: main (main.c:29)
==7322==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==7322==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==7322==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==7322==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==7322==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==7322== 
==7322== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7322==     in use at exit: 592 bytes in 4 blocks
==7322==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 1 frees, 600 bytes allocated
==7322== 
==7322== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7322==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7322==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7322==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7322==    still reachable: 592 bytes in 4 blocks
==7322==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7322== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==7322== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==7322== 
==7322== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7322== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[1]    7322 segmentation fault (core dumped)  valgrind --leak-check=full ./main
```

What is the problem with:

```
char** temp  = realloc(prefix, sizeof(char*) * (i+1));
```

??

Comment: You don't check the result of `fscanf` in the correct way.

Comment: `fscanf()` returns an `int`, not a `char`; that could lead to problems on some machines.  But it isn't the direct cause of your trouble.  You could use `for (i = 0; fscanf(file_prefix, "%s", buff) == 1; i++)` as the loop control (and remove the `i++` later).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fscanf` does not return `EOF`, it returns *the number of input items assigned* (`man fscanf`). For your purposes, you need to check

```
 while ( c == 1 )
   ...
```

However, that in itself does not cause the segfault! It is caused by attempting to print `prefix[i]` (repeatedly), which is not set to a correct value. You probably meant to print `prefix[x]` instead:

```
for (;x < i; ++x) {
  printf("%s\n", prefix[x]);
}
```

With these two corrections, your program runs without an error.

Answer (score 1):

- `fscanf` returns `int` so you should have:

  `int c = fscanf(file_prefix, "%s", buff);`

  Since `char` is the only type that can be `signed` or `unsigned` depending on implementation, your code actually might not be able to detect `EOF` condition. If `scanf` returns `EOF(-1)` and it is assigned to `unsigned char c` you will get 255. Condition in `while(c!=EOF){...}` loop will always be `true`.
- `fscanf` can return `EOF(-1)` or number of processed elements. In this case you want to have one string processed so you should check in the `while` loop:

  `while ( c == 1 ) { ... }`
- There is a bug in the last loop.

  `int x = 0; for (;x < i; ++x) {printf("%s\n", prefix[x]);} // change i to x`

After these changes program extracts words from file.